# What’s the use of "System version" in eclipse "Driver Definitions"?

Tags: java, eclipse, jdbc

Eclipse Data Tools Platform has a “Driver Definitions” entry, where you can indicate the JDBC drivers you want to use. When adding one, the wizard asks you to select a “driver template” from a provided list. In my eclipse Neon Java EE version, the list contains, among others, [Name=Other Driver; System Vendor=Derby; System Version=10.2], and [Name=Other Driver; System Vendor=Derby; System Version=10.1]. I can’t see a difference between these two templates, except that they end up with different indicated System Version as a result of the wizard (expectedly). However, in both cases (selecting the 10.2 line or the 10.1 line), when the wizard asks for a jar containing the driver, I use a jar containing the 10.10 version, so this indicated System Version is incorrect in both cases.

My questions are: how does eclipse use these version numbers? If it does not use them, why does eclipse bother displaying a list with different entries for different versions? Can I get problems if the version of the driver I use does not match the indicated one? Should I somehow tell eclipse the right version I use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The system version is the supported (minimum) version of the target database. The definition of a higher version can contain new features, keywords, data types etc of that database version. In other words: improved/closer support for the database version you are targeting.

For example on of the differences between the [Derby 10.1 definition](http://git.eclipse.org/c/datatools/org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.git/tree/plugins/org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.apache.derby.dbdefinition/runtime/vendors/Derby_10.1/Derby_10.1.xmi) and [Derby 10.2 definition](http://git.eclipse.org/c/datatools/org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.git/tree/plugins/org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.apache.derby.dbdefinition/runtime/vendors/Derby_10.2/Derby_10.2.xmi) is the default length reported for blobs:

In 10.1:

```
<predefinedDataTypeDefinitions xmi:id="BINARY_LARGE_OBJECT_1" lengthSupported="true" 
    defaultLength="1024" maximumLength="2147483647" primitiveType="BINARY_LARGE_OBJECT" jdbcEnumType="2004" javaClassName="java.sql.Blob">
```

In 10.2:

```
<predefinedDataTypeDefinitions xmi:id="BINARY_LARGE_OBJECT_1" lengthSupported="true" 
    defaultLength="2147483647" maximumLength="2147483647" primitiveType="BINARY_LARGE_OBJECT" jdbcEnumType="2004" javaClassName="java.sql.Blob">
```

Sometimes there might be no difference at all, but a separate (identical) definition might be provided just to avoid confusion for users to indicate that version is supported, and to make it easier to add corrections/improvements at a later time for that specific database version if necessary.

In short: use the version that is closest (but lower than or equal to) the version you are targetting; in this case: use the 10.2 definition.